# Is GetHashCode threadsafe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have this question.

```
public class Foo : object
{
    public override bool Equals(obj a, objb)
    {
       return ((Foo)a).Bar.GetHashCode() == ((Foo)b).Bar.GetHashCode();
}
```

}

Suppose I want to make Foo threadsafe.  Do I need to synchronize calls to GetHashCode()?

Comment: I was just trolling.  I'm impressed SO community came by and fixed it til there was a reasonable question+answer.  The question was tongue in cheek though, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you were going to add synchronization, what would you synchronize against?

I would say as a general rule `GetHashCode` **should** always be threadsafe, but the docs don't state a requirement for thread safety.  A consumer of `Bar` can't really guarantee it's usage is threadsafe unless `Bar` provides thread safety internally.

Let's say `Bar` uses two internal fields to calculate the hash code.  If another thread is in the process of updating the fields and only one has changed, you'll be able to get a `GetHashCode()` result after one field was updated but before the second was updated, unless `Bar` internally provides synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for `System.Object`:

> Public static members of this type are thread safe. Instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Thus, if you have not overrode `Object.GetHashCode` you have no guarantee of thread safety. If you have overrode it depends on your implementation. It also depends on what you mean by "[thread safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)."

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what Bar is.  If bar is a "readonly" string field on Foo, then it is thread-safe.  If bar is a read-write field holding an arbitrary value type with its own definition of GetHashCode() then there may be nothing thread-safe about your function at all.

It also depends on your definition of thread safety.  Do you define thread safety to mean that the returned value is consistent for all time?  If so, then there is no way for that to be guaranteed unless the value of Bar's hash code cannot change.  If not, then you have to acknowledge that the return value of this method could be incorrect given the current states of a and b before it has even returned.

If Bar can change, then this is perhaps an intractable problem.  If you try to lock a and b (or lock private mutexes in a and b), which order do you do it in?  What if the caller reverses the order of the parameters?  That will create a very straightforward deadlock.  Google the concept of a "lock hierarchy" to see the dangers therein.  If Bar can change, the only way to make this operation thread-safe is to lock write access to all Bar's that could be changed with one global lock prior to doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a compelling reason why you'd need to make `GetHashCode` thread-safe, and I could see it leading to deadlocks or at least lock convoys if you aren't careful; `GetHashCode` is called from a lot of places you might not expect.

What's more logical is that if you have multiple threads sharing a single `Foo`, those threads will need to *synchronize their access to the `Foo`*, so you simply don't have multiple threads calling `GetHashCode` at once (or any other method of `Foo`).

Correctly designing thread-safe classes can be a difficult exercise; unless you have a very good reason to require thread-safe instance members, I would choose not to do it.  The vast majority of the .NET Framework itself does not have thread-safe instance members.

Finally, there really isn't such a thing as a class being universally thread-safe.  You can synchronize every single instance member, but a consumer of your class can still mess it up if they don't understand the *semantics*.  Making `GetHashCode` thread-safe implies that you are trying to account for *every* conceivable threading scenario, but even most thread-safe classes are only thread-safe for *certain operations*, and `GetHashCode` is not normally one of them.

I'll refer you to Eric Lippert's recent [post on thread-safety](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx); think about the content of this when using a phrase such as "Make `Foo` thread-safe."